Sharing keycloak instance between react MF with vite-module-federation
I am facing the issue on how to share a keycloak instance between MF shared via vite-module-federation .
For security and identity management, I use the keycloak solution. For creation and sharing of microfrontends purposes, I use vite-module-federation. One of the federated modules provides redux store which allows to keep in sync all data shared between MFs. For API calls I use RTK Query.  Below is the simplified structure of the application:
<HostApp>
  <StoreProvider store={StoreMF.store}>
    <HeaderMF />
    <Footer MF />
  </StoreProvider>
</HostApp>

I am currently facing a problem with how to share the Keycloak instance between MFs. The Keycloak object initialisation is on the HostApp layer. I've read that class instances should not be stored in the redux store because class as itself breaks the immutability rule. For now I need to share data as token and userId to be able to make API calls independently in each MF.  In the future I would like to be able to force a logout with keycloak.logout and so on. This will probably require access to the keycloak instance. The question is, how should I share this object or its part to ensure that it is up to date and I do not create any vulnerability? Perhaps there is another approach that allows me to do this:

make API request independently in each MF

use a keycloak solution

take care of security


Thanks in advance for any help

Hi @Patryk, why don't you add an interceptor thus you can pass your token for every request that you fire?

When we are talking about interceptors in the RTQ I can extend the fetchBaseQuery as documentation said. The question is how to share token that will be updated via keycloack itself from host to remotes. Note that keycloak instance is in the HostApp. In which I launch <HeaderMF/> from where I make an API call using RTK Query that is imported via static paths as it will be one docker image.

Both your host and the remote(s) will run under the instance of your host. With MF you are just fetching the javascript code from a running server thus the host consumes it and uses that code. It’s not like the APIs are triggered from another app or browser tab. Thus if you do use an interceptor, all the APIs should go through it and you can inject your token from there. Now if you want to also to be able to run the standalones and have security then the standalones should have a wrapper component that will invoke keycloak as the host does
